# How to prevent countdown timer from skipping the first second?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hey there I'm trying to implement a countdown timer in react I have it mostly implemented but the issue is that it skips the very first second.
I know that it's because of the **Math.floor** but when I used **Math.ceil** it resulted in the timer stopping at 1 second remaining.
I also tried calling the **calculateTimeLeft** method(both in toggleEnabled and before setting the setTimeout) but it resulted in creating infinite recursion and I'm pretty much out of ideas.
Summary of the code:
**CountdownTimer.js**

```
const initialCountdownValue = {
    h: 0,
    i: 1,
    s: 0
};

const Digit = ({ number }) => {
    return (
        <span>{("0" + number.toString()).slice(-2)}</span>
    )
};

export const CountdownTimer = () => {
    const [enabled, setEnabled] = useState(false);
    const [countdownValue, setCountdownValue] = useState(initialCountdownValue);
    const [countdownEndDate, setCountdownEndDate] = useState(null);

    const calculateTimeLeft = () => {
        const now = new Date();

        const timeleft = countdownEndDate - now;
        if (timeleft < 0) {
            setEnabled(false);
            return;
        }

        const diff = DateUtil.difference(countdownEndDate, now);

        setCountdownValue({
            h: diff.hours,
            i: diff.minutes,
            s: diff.seconds,
        });
    }

    const toggleEnabled = () => {
        setEnabled(!enabled);
        if(!enabled) {
            const endDate = new Date();
            DateUtil.addTime(endDate, countdownValue);
            setCountdownEndDate(endDate);
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        let timer;
        if(enabled) {
            timer = setTimeout(calculateTimeLeft, 1000);
        }

        return () => timer && clearTimeout(timer);
    });

    return (
        <>
            <h1>
                <Digit number={countdownValue.h} />:<Digit number={countdownValue.i} />:<Digit number={countdownValue.s} /></h1>
            <button onClick={toggleEnabled}>{enabled ? "STOP" : "START"}</button>
        </>
    )
}
```

**DateUtil.js**

```
const time = (y,m,d,h,i,s) => {
    return {
        years: y,
        months: m,
        days: d,
        hours: h,
        minutes: i,
        seconds: s,
    };
}

const difference = (futureDate, currentOrPastDate) => {
    const diff = +futureDate - +currentOrPastDate;
    if (diff < 0) {
        return time(0,0,0,0,0,0);
    }
    
    return time(
        0,
        0,
        Math.floor(diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)),
        Math.floor((diff / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24),
        Math.floor((diff / 1000 / 60) % 60),
        Math.floor((diff / 1000) % 60),
    );
}

const addTime = (date, { y, m, d, h, i, s }) => {
    let timestamp = date.getTime();

    if(h) {
        timestamp += 1000 * 60 * 60 * h;
    }
    
    if (i) {
        timestamp += 1000 * 60 * i;
    }

    if (s) {
        timestamp += 1000 * s;
    }

    date.setTime(timestamp);
}

export const DateUtil = {
    difference,
    addTime,
};
```

Dont mind the y and m props in time they are not used anywhere(yet)
You can also experiment on your own on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-glade-1ef1g?file=/src/DateUtil.js:0-922)
I'd appreciate any help or hints on the issue, thanks in advance :)

Comment: this is not a solution. but have you tried to add one to the input so that it get skipped.

Comment: @AhmedGaafer what exactly do you mean? pleas clarify your comment

Comment: You said that the first second always gets skipped. 
so let's say that you take input from textbox in the code add 1 to the value of the textbox it will get skipped and the timer will work

Comment: @AhmedGaafer well that's sort of a workaround not really a long term solution creating unnecessary lines of code to maintain